# webpack with multiple angular 2 modules

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, webpack

I have an `ASP.NET Core` site with 2 pages, the page routing is done via `MVC`, not `Angular 2`. Each of those pages has its own `Angular 2` "app". I am having a real hard time trying to get this to work with `webpack`.

If I bootstrap both of the components into one module, then I get a `The selector "xxx" did not match any elements` error. However, if I try to create multiple `entry`s in the `webpack.config.js` then the `polyfills` freaks out because it is unable to find the other module.

How do I get this to work? Is the only option available to me here is to be forced to use the `Angular 2` router and create a SPA?

Here's the relevant portion of my `webpack.config.js`:

```
entry: {
    "polyfills": "./App/polyfills.ts",
    "vendor": "./App/vendor.ts",
    "firstapp": "./App/bootfirst.ts",
    "secondapp": "./App/bootsecond.ts"
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html']
},
output: {
    path: process.cwd() + "/wwwroot",
    publicPath: "/js/",
    filename: "js/[name].js"
},
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: What is the point of several modules? What are you trying to achieve? Also, I don't get the idea of downloading different angular apps on different pages.

Comment: do you mean this;  do you want to run a `ng app` on each controller?

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, I've had to use this atrocity to keep going. Please someone help me find the right solution to this.

```
entry: {
    "polyfills": "./App/polyfills.ts",
    "vendor": "./App/vendor.ts",
    "app": "./App/bootfirst.ts"
    //"app": "./App/bootsecond.ts"
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html']
},
output: {
    path: process.cwd() + "/wwwroot",
    publicPath: "/js/",
    filename: "js/[name].first.js"
    //filename: "js/[name].second.js"
},
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have two separate Angular apps for those two routes, then...

`ng build --prod ...` (i.e. create a production build) the two apps separately and put/host them in their own separate folders in your MVC app. No need of web-pack for this workaround.

I suppose loading the content (index.html) according to the .NET MVC Route is something you already know how to take care of. So when the respective route hits, it only loads the particular app in respective folder. There might be some deployment tweaking to be done based on the setups of your MVC project and Angular apps.

Comment: Yikes! Minus points! Did I misunderstand the question then? Or is it because my solution is worse?